# Android app is creating duplicated shortcut in homescreen

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

I run the app on emulator (and on phones) and it is creating 2 shortcuts in homescreen. If I delete the app, it removes both shortcuts.

My app have on `splash screen` then go to main screen and I'm using android studio.

I believe is related with `<intent-filter>` but each time i delete  when i run the app it appears again automatic on both `<activity>`.

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <receiver android:name="receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**EDIT:** 
Check this video to understand what happen when i follow your sugestions:

https://vid.me/onhe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove code below from MainActivity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Your SplashScreen will be the Root Activity of your app... So, those parameters are needed only for the SplashScreen.

**Final Result**

```
<!-- Splash screen -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.SplashScreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

**UPDATE**

I checked your picture.

I saw that you are updating following file:

```
app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

However, app/build file is a folder were Android Studio put the generated files...

Try to search for the manifest in your source code folder.. Something like:

```
app/src/... (or any other folder different from build)
```

Comment: Dont work. When i hit RUN on android studio. Automatic he add again :

`<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>`

To my mainActivity. I dont understand why.

Comment: @CarlosBranco Are you adding some library to your app? Or Something like that? Maybe, Android Studio is merging the manifest file with another one...

Comment: My project is pretty small. 
http://i.imgur.com/2Lo80Yl.png

Check this. hmmm i dont understand why this happen .

Comment: hello can you check the video give you a better idea:
https://vid.me/onhe

Comment: @CarlosBranco I updated my answer... please, check it out

Comment: Thank you so much . I was editing a file hmm that was like a cache file i dont even know how i open it.  I close that file and open manist again now its ok.
Thank you.

Comment: Good to know!!! Kindly request to accept the answer if it worked to you... best regards

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest should be one MAIN action and also one LAUNCHER intent-filter which is starting activity for your applicaiton

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Only for root activity of your application.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <receiver android:name="receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.epicbit.tecnoprolab.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Dont work. My Android studio add <intent-filter> to all activity each time i remove it when i run the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, duplicate icons were created after an app upgrade. In this upgrade we introduced Splash Screen. Its because we have renamed the launcher activity. We moved the

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

to Splash screen activity from the MainActivity.

In some phones, renaming of activity is creating duplicate icons.
Wierd. Renaming activities helped here.

Reproducible in OnePlus One phone.